# Image filling vertical space in container

Tags: html, css

I've got a `<div>` with an image on the left side and some text on the right side.
How can I achieve that the image always fills the vertical space?

This is how its supposed to look:

[image]

The parent's height will change in 3 steps using media queries.

Comment: Will the parent `div` have a specified height?

Comment: Yes it will. I will just change the parent's height in 3 steps according to the screenwidth with media-queries.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/m77tekey/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should make all images in your div reach from the top to the bottom.

```
<div id="content">
    <img src="source.jpg">
    Other div contents...
</div

#content img { 
    height: 100%;
}
```